# how to show reCaptcha in phone authentication firebase react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

When I'm going to authenticate with phone number I get this error [image]

how can I use reCaptcha  I can't use safe net Method in phone authentication because my country is not exist when I want to create google cloud account.
this is my code.

please help me and if you have a good doc for solving this problem send me its link

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  measurementId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export default () => {
  return { firebase, auth };
};
```

```
const SignUPScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { auth } = firebaseSetup();
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(null);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
      setConfirm(confirmation);
      navigation.navigate('OTP', { confirm: confirm });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        placeholder="Enter your phone number"
        keyboardType="phone-pad"
        onChangeText={(text) => setPhoneNumber(text)}
      />
      <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={() => signIn()} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Alert, Button, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

const OTP = ({ route }) => {
  const { confirm } = route.params;
  const [code, setCode] = useState('');
  const confirmCode = async () => {
    try {
      await confirm.confirm(code);
      Alert.alert('User sign in SuccessFully');
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Invalid code');
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        placeholder="Enter the OTP code"
        value={code}
        onChangeText={(text) => setCode(text)}
      />
      <Button title="Confirm Code" onPress={() => confirmCode()} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem is due to SHA1.
I had filled in an wrong SHA1 key in the Firebase console.
I change it with correct SHA1 then the error have been gone.